How do I change this topology to "quads"?

How can I change the topology of this model to quads.

hello could you please share your file? Also, do you abolutely need quads?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

@moonboots , tris might also work, just want a clean simple and low topology, this is too complicated

you can select all and X > Limited Dissolve, it will remove all the inner edges, and some vertices if you increase the Max Angle value, but maybe tell a bit more about your goal?

@moonboots I want to solidify it and then apply subdivision on it. With this topology the subdivision is very bad

So maybe press X > Limited DIssolve, create a bevel along the edges? Share your file if it doesn't work

Try selecting them all, go to the Face dropdown menu and click on beatify faces. Then Ctrl+J to merge the triangles into quads. You'll probably still need manual adjusting after.
Either that or you can just extrude the part and put a Sharp Remesh modifier on it. It should create decent quads

I would just show it with a GIF if you shared the model, but I can try to explain with text.
Enabling LoopTools and F2 add-ons is probably a good idea for this. You can do that in Preferences( F4  ->  P ), Add-ons tab searching for them by name:

So I would just select the boundary loops by  Alt +clicking on outer edges or selecting the whole mesh and then going to Select menu->Select Loops->Select Boundary Loop, then invert the selection( Ctrl  +  I ) and delete edges( X  ->  E ), then I would clean the straight parts by dissolving vertices( Ctrl  +  X ) where they are not needed. Next I would fill the sticking out parts by selecting outer edge and hitting  F  to call the F2 functionality(it does so much, I am not sure what to call it :D ) and fill them. I would need to make sure there is the same amount of vertices on edge loop segments on both sides of the sticking out parts. I could dissolve or add vertices(with  Ctrl  +  R  or  Right Click  -> Subdivide) and then I could use Space function from LoopTools to space them evenly, and Relax to make them follow general curvature better if needed. Loop tools are in the Sidebar("n-panel"):

Or you can find them using search( F3/ Space  ).
Then I would need to make sure the rest of the edge loops have the same amount of vertices. You can see selected vert count in the Status Bar, if you enable Scene Statistics in its right-click menu:

Same principle: add or remove vertices until the counts match, Space and Relax to even them out and then fill them either with Bridge Loops

Or with F2( F ).

Actually even without having the file, looking at the object with everything triangulated, I'm 100% sure Alt+click to select edge loops will not work, and 99% sure Select Boundary Loops will not work either. I would start with selecting all, then X > Limited Dissolve with a low threshold angle. //EDIT: I just realized it is a flat planar object, I thought it was already extruded in some way. Of course then your suggestions will work. But Limited Dissolve is still a good way to clean up the mesh.

You can also use the Remesh modifier.

Click on the Remesh modifier, then make sure that Sharp is selected. Uncheck Remove Disconnected and increase the Octree Depth to the level that makes your mesh resemble the original structure, but you'll have quads instead of triangles.
